# 15th-level gestalt stealth master build help

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization

I am trying to make a character for a combat heavy, largely PvP game, with 15th-level gestalt characters. The concept that I have in mind is some sort of Jack-of-All-Trades-y Wizard/Rogue class, with a heavy focus on defence, stealth, and mind magic. A lot of the other players seem to have built characters that have some sort of anime-ultraform where they grow 50 feet tall (at least 3), and so I thought it could be cool to contrast that. Since I’m a new player, I figured that defence would help me survive combat a while longer.

There seems to be a lot of classes to go through, and I’m not quite sure what the best path to take is. Due to the nature of the game, the character should be pretty optimized.

From my look at the classes, the ones that seemed most interesting were rogue, wizard, arcanist, magus, summoner, and investigator. Rogue and wizard were the original concept, but I’m not entirely certain what the difference between arcanist, magus, and wizard is. Summoner sounds cool and like it has abilities well suited to arena combat. I’m not certain which is better between Unchained Rogue and Investigator, but if investigator is good, the spell slots and alchemy might be a useful / interesting add on.

The race I want to play is Gnome, but with the extra Race Points, that can be buffed quite a bit.

The info from the GM:

> **Level 15, gestalt.** Leadership or Monstrous companion required.
> **Mythic Tier 1**
> **Races**: up to 30 race points. Yes, you can add abilities to an existing race to get it up to 30 race points. I am ruling Powerful Build as 3 race points. If there are other traits from psionic, etc races that you are interested in, ask and we can figure out a cost. Race point details here
> **Classes**: Piazo, Path of War (dreamscarred press only), Akashic (dreamscarred press only), Psionic (dreamscarred press only) for sure. Maybe spheres (I'm not that familiar so it will take a lot more work for me, if we do it, it will be drop dead studios only). NO high-tech options
> **Stats**: 25 point buy
> **Oaths**: Yes, you can use the spheres oaths. Expect them to be strictly enforced by evil genies who would also love to grant some wishes.
> Starting funds: **240,000 GP**
> **Hit Points** Max at 1st level, better of roll or avg at all other levels
> **Feats**: Use the EitR pdf version and take leadership for free

The premise and setting of the game is that each character has been chosen by the Gods to compete in a competition to become a new God. The PvP combat takes place in arena-style one-on-one combat, for the most part, though the GM has hinted there may also be group challenges. The characters only interaction with the outside world will be their ally from the Leadership trait, and between arena duels, the allies will have conflicts that will not be solely PvP, but rely upon more nuanced skills. There is one round of preparation time pre-combat in the arena, though anything with a duration of more than an hour can be pre-cast (including permanent spells). I build the cohort. I will ask about the crafting between matches, I would assume yes.

Crafting while building is not allowed. The GM reserves the right to say that certain classes don’t work as gestalt, as the gestalt rules say. 3.x content is probably not allowed, though if there is no good alternative in Pathfinder, they may be willing to discuss allowing it.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty advanced game. Those character stats are beyond what min-maxxers even use because they're better than the default. Does that still appeal to you? If so, I think we'll need you to narrow it down further. I think what parts about the classes you mention appeal to you would be a good start, and if you have any more specific goals than stealth, defense, and mind magic (Enchantment?).

Comment: Has the GM provided any examples of characters to serve as models?

Comment: VTC for now, because currently this question is very much unclear and and answers will be heavily opinion-based (i.e. no criteria for rating the myriad builds). This also seems like a question more suited for a forum than for SE.

Comment: Things that very much need to be clarified for this question. Is crafting while building your character allowed? What's the GM's policy on binding outsiders into your service? Is there any content that's banned (I only see restrictions on the classes)? What's the setting that this PvP focused game occurs in? Are the characters expected to restrict their actions into a single city (if so. vigilante could be good), or does it span the world?

Comment: @willuwontu I believe I have clarified everything you asked. (As well as the other comments but I can only mention one person).

Comment: "PvP combat takes place in arena-style one-on-one combat", this raises far more questions. Are pre-buffs allowed? If so, is there a minimum duration for them? What about permanencied spells? If you're not allowed to craft during character creation, are you allowed to craft between matches? If so, how much time will you have each time? Is the GM building your cohort or are you creating them? What are the rules for combat in the arena? Etc.

Comment: @willuwontu there is one round of preparation time pre-combat, though anything with a duration of more than an hour can be pre-cast (including permanent spells). I build the cohort.  I will ask about the crafting between matches, I would assume yes.

Comment: What does the arena look like? What size is it? Is it a consistent layout? Does it change each time? Are you using a VTT for the combats, minis, or theater of the mind? Does the One-on-One combat exclude companions, familiars, and the like from joining you? What about things like crafted companions? Can you bring them into the arena with you? You mentioned pre-buffing is allowed, can you use that time to cast spells with unlimited range and no LoS/LoE reqs on opponents? Can you interact with opponents outside of the arena? Are battles to the death only, or are there other win conditions?

Comment: Are you allowed to go into the ethereal plane while fighting (i.e. using the blink spell, ethereal jaunt, etc) since it borders the material plane and just overlays it? What about the shadow plane which also borders the material plane? What if you send opponents to other planes?

Comment: Another thing to consider is how are consumables being handled? Do they permanently go away and reduce your WBL with each match they get used in? Are they restocked for free before each match so that competitors have the same WBL? Etc.

Comment: Also, are you allowed to access spells higher than you'd normally be able to cast at level 15, (i.e. 9th-level spells)?

Comment: @willuwontu yes ethereal and shadow, no to other planes. No sending an opponent outside of the arena (I.e. to another plane). Consumables are used up, but the ally can purchase more and bring them. You are allowed access to higher level spells.

Comment: What type of terrain does the arena count as for things like ranger favored terrain? [Also, my earlier questions about it and other things.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205410/15th-level-gestalt-stealth-master-build-help#comment562921_205410)

Comment: @willuwontu The arena and it’s favoured terrain changes every time, though the first match up is just sand, with no obstacles. Theatre of the mind. The first arena is 600 by 300 feet. Anything that can be summoned can join. You cannot attack opponents before the match begins. Battles are to the death, but the GM ‘may accept other conditions, such as paralysis of a sufficiently long duration’.